# BigQuery Legacy SQL to Standard SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have multiple tables let's call them Bs that I first join each of them w/
another table called A and then merge their results all together.

Here is the legacy SQL solution. Number of B tables in this example is 2.

```sql
SELECT
  A.ID,
  A.start AS start,
  A.END AS END,
  CONCAT("B1: ",B1.Info ),
  CONCAT("B2: ",B2.Info )
FROM (
  SELECT
    A.ID,
    A.start,
    A.END,
    B1.Info
  FROM (
    SELECT
      *
    FROM A
  JOIN
    B1
  ON
    (B1.ID = A.ID)
    AND (B1.start = A.start)
    AND (B1.END = A.END)
  WHERE
    (...)
  GROUP BY
    A.ID,
    A.start,
    A.END,
    B1.Info),
  (
  SELECT
    A.ID,
    A.start,
    A.END,
    CONCAT(B2.Infor_I, "/",B2.Info_J) AS B2.Info
  FROM (
    SELECT
      *
    FROM  A
  JOIN
    B2
  ON
    (B2.ID = A.ID)
    AND (B2.start = A.start)
    AND (B2.END = A.END)
  WHERE
    (...)
  GROUP BY
    A.ID,
    A.start,
    A.END,
    B2.Info)
```

I assumed legacy SQL will first run subqueries (A-B1), (A-B2), ... (A-Bn) in parallel and then merge all together. What would be the efficient way of solving this problem using SQL standard?

Thanks!

Comment: Basic replace the comma with `UNION ALL`.

Comment: Do you mean UNION ALL between subqueries?

Comment: . . Yes, that would be the effect.

Comment: Thanks. If you have different numbers of fields then what would you do?  I tried `Select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5 from Table1
Union
Select Col1, Col2, Col3, Null as Col4, Null as Col5 from Table2`; it didn't work.

Comment: . . Exactly.  Use `NULL` as the placeholder.

Comment: Then, how would you merge the results for those having the same ID, start and end? Using Max would not only eliminate NULL but for those having multiple values, it only picks one of them. How can I get rid of NULL in such case? Thanks!